# Ошибка при десериализации json в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Нужно реализовать key-value хранилище, при получении значения по ключу выдает ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "storage.py", line 36, in <module>
json_data = json.load(f)  

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

Программа:

```
import os, sys, argparse, json, tempfile

def get_key(d, key):
    for v, k in d.keys():
        if k == key:
            return v


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--key', dest = 'key_name')
parser.add_argument('--val', dest = 'value')

args = parser.parse_args()

my_dict = {}
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
if os.path.isfile(u'/tmp/storage.data') == False:            
    if args.key_name != None:
        if args.value != None: 
            with open(storage_path, 'w') as f:
                json_dp = json.dump(my_dict.update([(args.key_name,args.value)]),f)
    else:
        print(None)
else:
    if args.key_name != None: 
        if args.value != None:  
            with open(storage_path, 'a') as f: 
                json_dp = json.dump(my_dict.update([(args.key_name,args.value)]), f) 

        else: 
            with open(storage_path, 'r') as f: 
               json_data = json.load(f)   
               print(get_key(json_data, args.key_name))
```

Comment: Вы пробовали открыть storage_path в обычном текстовом редакторе и почитать, что там написано?

Comment: Открыла, там : nullnullnullnullnull

Comment: что вы думаете `my_dict.update()` возвращает?

Answer (score 1):

Починил.

Проблема была в `json.dump(my_dict.update(...`, т.к. `update` возвращает `None`, а оно в `json` интерпретируется как `null`, что получается как `json.dump(None, ...`, поэтому у автора в файле были `nullnullnullnullnull`.

Ну и проблему мог вызвать файл открытый как `a` (`open(storage_path, 'a'))` – при сохранении словаря, нужно было переписать файл им (флаг `w`), а не добавить, т.к. после второго добавления мы получаем невалидный `json`.

```
import argparse
import json
import os


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--key', dest='key_name')
    parser.add_argument('--val', dest='value')

    return parser.parse_args()


def read_storage(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        storage = json.load(f)

    return storage


def save_storage(storage, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(storage, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()

    storage = dict()
    storage_file_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'storage.data')
    print('Storage:', storage_file_name)

    key = args.key_name
    val = args.value

    if not os.path.exists(storage_file_name):
        if key and val:
            storage[key] = val
            print('Key "{}" = {}'.format(key, val))

            save_storage(storage, storage_file_name)

    else:
        storage = read_storage(storage_file_name)

        if key:
            if val:
                storage[key] = val
                print('Key "{}" = {}'.format(key, val))

                save_storage(storage, storage_file_name)

            else:
                print('Key "{}" -> {}'.format(key, storage.get(key)))
```